# Can i get email address from twitter user using tweepy and python?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

hi I have the json from verify_credentials because the user give me access with my app developed in twitter but i can't find how i can see the email because in the "dir (api)" not have a method for it and i dont have more ideas about this problem, i use jupyter and tweepy, any idea?

`api= tweepy.API(auth) 
api.verify_credentials() with this i can see the json
dir(api)`

this is the code what is develop for this problem.

my question is how i can see the email address from one twitter user if i can access from python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but for that you need to enable addition permission on your twitter app

> The “Request email addresses from users” checkbox is available under the app permissions on [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com). Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields must be completed in the app settings in order for email address access to function. If enabled, users will be informed via the oauth/authorize dialog that your app can access their email address.

Sample Request
`GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json`

Example Response

```
 {
    "contributors_enabled": true,
    "created_at": "Sat May 09 17:58:22 +0000 2009",
    "default_profile": false,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "description": "I taught your phone that thing you like.  The Mobile Partner Engineer @Twitter. ",
    "favourites_count": 588,
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "followers_count": 10625,
    "following": null,
    "friends_count": 1181,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "id": 38895958,
    "id_str": "38895958",
    "is_translator": false,
    "lang": "en",
    "listed_count": 190,
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "name": "Sean Cook",
    "notifications": null,
    "profile_background_color": "1A1B1F",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/495742332/purty_wood.png",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/495742332/purty_wood.png",
    "profile_background_tile": true,
    "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1751506047/dead_sexy_normal.JPG",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1751506047/dead_sexy_normal.JPG",
    "profile_link_color": "2FC2EF",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "181A1E",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "252429",
    "profile_text_color": "666666",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "protected": false,
    "screen_name": "theSeanCook",
    "show_all_inline_media": true,
    "status": {
        "contributors": null,
        "coordinates": {
            "coordinates": [
                -122.45037293,
                37.76484123
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "created_at": "Tue Aug 28 05:44:24 +0000 2012",
        "favorited": false,
        "geo": {
            "coordinates": [
                37.76484123,
                -122.45037293
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "id": 240323931419062272,
        "id_str": "240323931419062272",
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": "messl",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 240316959173009410,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "240316959173009410",
        "in_reply_to_user_id": 18707866,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "18707866",
        "place": {
            "attributes": {},
            "bounding_box": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -122.45778216,
                            37.75932999
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.44248216,
                            37.75932999
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.44248216,
                            37.76752899
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.45778216,
                            37.76752899
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "country": "United States",
            "country_code": "US",
            "full_name": "Ashbury Heights, San Francisco",
            "id": "866269c983527d5a",
            "name": "Ashbury Heights",
            "place_type": "neighborhood",
            "url": "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/866269c983527d5a.json"
        },
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "retweeted": false,
        "source": "Twitter for  iPhone",
        "text": "@messl congrats! So happy for all 3 of you.",
        "truncated": false
    },
    "statuses_count": 2609,
    "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "url": null,
    "utc_offset": -28800,
    "verified": false }
```

Refer twitter [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) for details